What factors determine if there are dry summers in temperate regions (Csb and Dsb climates)?
Northwestern California, western Oregon and southwestern Washington as well as northern Portugal, parts of northern Spain and Brittany have a Csb climate, i.e. they are temperate yet have dry summers like Mediterranean (Csa) climates and unlike all-year-humid temperate climates (Cfb, Dfb). What is the determining factor in that? Why do they have dry summers despite being not so hot and why does the Pacific coast of North America have a larger Csb climate region than the Atlantic coast of Europe?

I think njuffa brings up a good point.  In addition, the presence of mountain ranges along the east-Pacific causes wetter conditions near the coast due to orographic effects.

In the summer, when the jet stream moves north, a high pressure system usually forms in the North Pacific, blocking rain events.  And as njuffa eluded to, the cold California current flows south, so the marine air is cool along the west coast.  So, dry in the summer, but not too hot because the cool marine air is constrained by the Cascades.

@f.thorpe I see.
